# Multiple Encryption in java

Tags: encryption

Hi I was looking for an example that will achieve multiple encryption in java , i.e encryption same piece of string or data multiple times so that i have layers of encryption.

The reason I want to achieve this is,As part of my university project I am trying to send some data from one machine to 3 hops and then destination. When sender sends it, it encrypts it with public key of destination ,encrypts again with 3rd hop's public key and so on, so when 1st hops recives it, it can only decrypt one layer and will find instrucitons to send to next hop, 2nd hop repeats the same process and passess it on to 3rd and same again untill it gets destination. This is so that none of the hops in the middle are able to see the data.

Thanks

Comment: Check out [Tor's paper](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=2572692611151874520&hl=zh-CN&as_sdt=0,5).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about an encrypted file, it is just a stream of bytes.  Encrypt it as you would any other file.